# R drop and element from a nested list using laply

Tags: r, lapply, nested-lists

I have nested list, the elements in the list are strings. So the structure is ...

```
> lapply(DVHlimits, function(x) laply (x, function(x) laply(x, function(x) length(x))))
[[1]]
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 [1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [5,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

 [[2]]
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 [1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

[[3]]
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

etc ......

What I want to do is drop the 8th element from each of sublists (where there is an 8th element) Can anyone tell me how to remove them?

Thank you

Comment: Please show a reproducible example using `dput`  From what is showed, it is not clear about the expected as we don't know your original example

Comment: From what i understand, you want `lapply` to skip some "rows" right?. If yes, then `lapply` always return a list with the same length as it's input. But the good news is you an customize the **function** and add a condition in it to skip the data you want. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543307/r-lapply-function-skipping-the-current-function-loop

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions, this is the solution that I came up with.

```
# Create a function which can be used with lapply 
cleanColls <- function(x) {
  x <- x[c(-1, -8)]
}

DVHlimits <- lapply(DVHlimits, function(x) lapply( x, function(x) cleanColls(x)))
```

As you can probably figure out I have also dropped the first element of each sublist. The end result is each sublist has now only 6 elements, they are now all the same length which is what I wanted to achieve.